# Java Regular expression find and update

Tags: java, regex

I need to add couple of import statements in every file in java project. I have written regular expression to perform this activity.

```
File1.java
/**********************
*
*History Card
*
***********************/
package com.employee.details;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;

public class File1
{

// java code
}

File2.java

package com.employee.details;
/**********************
*
*History Card
*
***********************/
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;

public class File1
{

// java code
}
```

Code to Perform the update:

```
String regEx = "^package .*;";
String pattern = "\0\n\nimport java.io.FileReader;\nimport java.nio.file.Path;";
textFile.replaceAll(regEx,pattern);
```

it's not working. whats wrong in my code? please help me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a) the comment at the beginning of the file, b) the greedy quantifier, and c) the missing variable assignment. Probably a removed package declaration as well. You should be using this code:

```
String regex = "(package .*?;)";
String replacement = "$1\0\n\nimport java.io.FileReader;\nimport java.nio.file.Path;";
textFile = textFile.replaceFirst(regex, replacement);
```

Strings in Java (in most languages, in fact) are immutable, and thus you can't change every instance of that string at once without a very large amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the java uses the dollar sign flavour of back references, not the backslash flavour.

In your replacement, `\0` is a `nul` char (hex zero), *not* group zero. Change it to `$0`:

```
String pattern = "$0\n\nimport java.io.FileReader;\nimport java.nio.file.Path;";
                  ^----- backslash changed to dollar sign
```

Comment: I thought `\0` is a [backreference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html#backref). Am I wrong?

Comment: @Ilya you are wrong. `\0` is a back reference in some other languages, but not Java, where it is the nul character (`0x00` or `\u0000`). In Java, back references have the form `$n`, where n is 0-9, group zero being the entire match.

Answer (score -1):

@RamenChef is almost right except that grouping (i.e. `(` and `)`) is not necessary and backreference (i.e. `\0`) too. So next code will work:

```
String regEx = "^package .*;";
String pattern = "$0\n\nimport java.io.FileReader;\nimport java.nio.file.Path;";
textFile = textFile.replaceAll(regEx,pattern);
```

Note only difference between your code and this is dollar sign before 0 and assigning of `replaceAll` result to `textFile` because `String` type is [immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: Why couldn't you just comment on my answer?

Comment: @RamenChef cause comments don't allow to post pretty formatted code.